# UICollectionView : animation custom layout

Tags: ios, animation, layout, uicollectionview

I'm displaying lots of image cells in an UICollectionView.
With one button I would like to be able to group all my cell over the first one.

This is working well but when I'm trying to add an animation transition to my regroup action, nothing happens.

Here the method I use in a custom layout :

```
- (NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray* allAttributesInRect = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    if([allAttributesInRect count] > 0 && _isRegroup)
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *firstAttribute = [allAttributesInRect objectAtIndex:0];
        CGRect frame = firstAttribute.frame;

        for(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in allAttributesInRect)
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{attribute.frame = frame;}];
    }
    return allAttributesInRect;
}

- (void)regroupCells:(BOOL)isRegroup // This method is called from my collection controller when my button is pressed
{
    _isRegroup = isRegroup;
    [self invalidateLayout];
}
```

Any idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Animations won't work from within the method you are calling them from.

To change the layout and animate to a new one, the simplest method is to call `performBatchUpdates` on your collection view, with `nil` for each block parameter. This invalidates your layout and animates to the new one for you.

Before doing this, you'd tell the layout object that you want the new layout to occur. Also, inside `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`, simply check your Boolean variable and apply the grouped frame (probably center would be better) to all attributes as you are doing now, but without animation. You'll also need to reproduce this code in `layoutAttributesForElementAtIndexPath`.

So, in summary:

1. Remove your invalidate layout call from where it is
2. Remove the animation calls from where they are, just amend the layout attributes
3. Add ..forElementAtIndexPath code as well
4. In your view controller, call the regroup method on the layout object, then call performBatchupdates on the collection view.

Comment: Here's the result for those who want to see :) http://d.pr/v/QUTF (I have a glitch problem)

Comment: You need to increase the z index for the "top" item in the stack, you can do that in the same place as you adjust the frame.

Comment: I already did that but it seems the problem is elsewhere. with slow animation enabled : http://d.pr/v/oEm4

Comment: I see. You should ask a separate question.

Comment: @Pierre The link http://d.pr/v/QUTF doesn't seem to work. can you share your implementation?