# App crashes on call to setNeedsDisplay for custom button

Tags: ios, swift, setneedsdisplay

I've custom button, app crashes randomly on call to `setNeedsDisplay`. How to fix this crash?

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customButton: CustomButton!

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        self.customButton.setNeedsDisplay() // Random crash here
    }
}

class CustomButton: UIButton {
    // ....

    override func setNeedsDisplay() {
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-29, bottom: 4.0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Crash log

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000104fb3f48
>
> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread 0  myapp                    0x104fb3f48
>   MyVC.viewWillTransition(to:with:) + 63 (MyVC.swift:63) 1  myapp
>       0x104fb3f88 @objc MyVC.viewWillTransition(to:with:)
>   () 2  UIKitCore                      0x1ee286708
>   -[UIViewController viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 868 3 
>   UIKitCore                      0x1ee1e596c -[UINavigationController
>   viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 84 4  UIKitCore
>   0x1ee286708 -[UIViewController
>   viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 868 5 
>   UIKitCore                      0x1ee1b46dc -[UITabBarController
>   viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 48 6  UIKitCore
>   0x1ee27ba18 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] +
>   112 7  UIKitCore                      0x1ee292a24
>   -[UIViewController(AdaptiveSizing) _window:viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 580 8  UIKitCore                      0x1ee8537c4 **59-[UIWindow
>   _rotateToBounds:withAnimator:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 188 9  UIKitCore                      0x1eeca08f0 +[UIView(Animation)
>   performWithoutAnimation:] + 104 10 UIKitCore
>
>   0x1ee853618 -[UIWindow
>   _rotateToBounds:withAnimator:transitionContext:] + 412 11 UIKitCore                      0x1ee855e24 -[UIWindow
>   _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:] + 1184 12 UIKitCore                      0x1ee8564d8 -[UIWindow
>   _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:]
>   + 516 13 UIKitCore                      0x1ee8558d8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 128 14 UIKitCore                      0x1ee854584 __57-[UIWindow
>   _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 124 15 UIKitCore                      0x1ee854488 -[UIWindow
>   _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 560 16 UIKitCore                      0x1ee0dcfe0 -[_UICanvasMetricsCalculator
>   updateMetricsOnWindows:animated:] + 624 17 UIKitCore
>
>   0x1ee0e1990 -[_UICanvas _computeMetrics:] + 180 18 UIKitCore
>
>   0x1eeca08f0 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104 19
>   UIKitCore                      0x1ee0e04a8 -[_UICanvas
>   _performActions:withOverrideSettings:] + 172 20 UIKitCore                      0x1ee821b0c -[UIApplication
>   _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:] + 404 21 UIKitCore                      0x1ee8232f0 __65-[UIApplication
>   _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 124 22 FrontBoardServices             0x1c4b51768 -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction
>   _executeNextRequest] + 256 23 FrontBoardServices             0x1c4b517b8 -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _executeNextRequest] + 336 24
>   FrontBoardServices             0x1c4b51358 -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction
>   executeRequestsWithHandler:completionHandler:expirationHandler:] + 276
>   25 UIKitCore                      0x1ee823220 __65-[UIApplication
>   _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke + 268 26 UIKitCore                      0x1ee822848 -[UIApplication
>   _beginSnapshotSessionForScene:withSnapshotBlock:] + 744 27 UIKitCore                      0x1ee822f74 -[UIApplication
>   _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:] + 208 28 UIKitCore                      0x1ee822e40 -[UIApplication
>   _handleSnapshotAction:forScene:completion:] + 156 29 UIKitCore                      0x1ee81e724 __71-[UIApplication
>   _handleSnapshotAction:forScene:deactivationCompletion:]_block_invoke + 332 30 UIKitCore                      0x1ee81e540 -[UIApplication
>   _handleSnapshotAction:forScene:deactivationCompletion:] + 340 31 UIKitCore                      0x1ee0d9f58
>   __98-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability deactivateEventsOnly:withContext:forceExit:completion:]_block_invoke.261
>   + 820 32 UIKitCore                      0x1ee8220ac _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 296 33 UIKitCore                      0x1ee810bfc _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 352 34
>   UIKitCore                      0x1ee83da6c _afterCACommitHandler + 116
>   35 CoreFoundation                 0x1c212ed08
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 32 36 CoreFoundation                 0x1c2129a30 __CFRunLoopDoObservers +
>   412 37 CoreFoundation                 0x1c2129fac __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1228 38 CoreFoundation                 0x1c21297c0
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 39 GraphicsServices
>   0x1c432a79c GSEventRunModal + 104 40 UIKitCore
>   0x1ee816c38 UIApplicationMain + 212 41 myapp
>   0x104db7454 main + 20 (ProfileVC.swift:20) 42 libdyld.dylib
>   0x1c1bed8e0 start + 4

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the complete error message from the crash.

Comment: you posted the code `self.custom.setNeedsDisplay()` and say that is the line that crashes. However, you don't show the definition of `custom`. Should that be `customButton`, not `custom`? Don't paraphrase your code - post the actual code.

Comment: I've updated question, it's customButton.

Comment: You didn't post the error message. The stack trace is irrelevant since you already pointed out the problematic line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your line that crashes should actually read:

```
self.customButton.setNeedsDisplay() // Random crash here
```

The problem is likely that `customButton` is nil. You've declared `customButton` as an implicitly unwrapped optional. That means that the compiler unwraps it for you when you try to reference it. Try adding:

```
print("self.customButton = \(self.customButton?)")
self.customButton.setNeedsDisplay() // Random crash here
```

And look at the debug log. I'm guessing that you'll see something like:

> self.customButton = Optional(nil)

Comment: Yes that is what I also suspected that customButton is nil. Does it mean this button is not initialised in storyboard when this function is called? Do I need to guard this statement to fix this issue?

Comment: When a view controller is instantiated from a storyboard/xib its views aren't loaded immediately. I haven't used `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` in quite a while, and don't remember if it gets called before the target view controller's views are loaded or not. This would be a good case for optional chaining: `self.customButton?.setNeedsDisplay()` (Note the added question mark.) In optional chaining, if the optional being unwrapped is nil, the method doesn't get called, but execution continues with the next line.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. I'll fix it in the way you have explained.